# How to enable and disable scripts on a Game Object?

Tags: unity, c#, component-based, gameobject

This worked briefly yesterday, I believe I did something to mess this up. All my inputs that I put in are correct; therefor, it must be the code. I want to switch players. While the red cube's script is enabled and can move under the movement script I want the blue cubes movement script to be disabled and vice versus. Can you give me some insight into what I'm doing wrong? Please and thank you!!

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class PlayerMovementScript : MonoBehaviour {

    public float speed = 2f;
    public float height = 2f;

    public Component playerMovement;
    public GameObject redCube;
    public GameObject blueCube;

    void Start() 
    {
        var bc = blueCube.GetComponent<PlayerMovementScript>();

        bc.enabled = !bc.enabled;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () 
    {   
        if (Input.GetButton ("Right")) 
        {
            transform.Translate(Vector3.right * speed * Time.deltaTime);
        }

        if (Input.GetButton ("Left")) 
        {
            transform.Translate(Vector3.left * speed * Time.deltaTime);
        }

        if (Input.GetButton ("Jump")) 
        {
            transform.Translate(Vector3.up * height * Time.deltaTime);
        }

        var bc = blueCube.GetComponent<PlayerMovementScript>();
        var rc = redCube.GetComponent<PlayerMovementScript>();

        if (Input.GetButton ("Switch")) 
        {
            bc.enabled = !bc.isActiveAndEnabled;
            rc.enabled = !rc.enabled;
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: What is your issue and what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Exactly, what's current behavior and what you aim at?

Comment: @AlexandreVaillancourt and Leggy7 I want to switch players. While the red cube's script is enabled and can move under the movement script I want the blue cubes movement script to be disabled and vice versus.

Comment: it sounds to me like you need to read on the isActive and isEnabled flags in the Unity docs

Comment: @Stephan, this is a case of *alternate* implementation, not *incorrect* implementation. `isActive` and `isEnabled` *were* booleans under `GameObject` (IIRC); this implementation uses the *component* type (note that the cubes are stored as script references, I.e. components, *not* game objects. Also note that `isActive` and `isEnabled` have both been deprecated and removed. *You won't find these variables any more*, when reading the current API.

Comment: @Gnemlock it's been a while since I made this post, but I seem to recall looking in the API prior to making the suggestion. I have a feeling the deprecation has happened in the interim between my comment and yours. If not, my mistake! :)

Answer (score 1):

I eliminated the script's start function and just called the components in the update function.

```
var bc = blueCube.GetComponent<PlayerMovementScript>();
        var rc = redCube.GetComponent<PlayerMovementScript>();

        if (Input.GetButton ("Switch")) 
        {
            bc.enabled = !bc.enabled;
            rc.enabled = !rc.enabled;
```

Comment: Please note that you are not really doing anything different, of we can assume your `Start` method calls (if it does not, that's an entirely different problem, and an entirely different question). This suggests that removing `bc.enabled = !bc.enabled` from `Start`, and copying this line over `bc.enabled = BC.isActiveAndEnabled` in your `"Switch"` button solved the problem. *This is helpful in knowing why it happened in the first place*. Please mark this as the accepted answer, to let others know this worked.